# Angular 2 Fetch Data in local file

Tags: json, angular, http

I am new in Angular 2.

I would like to fetch data in a local JSON file. But I got errors in console like below:

[image: Error Message]

Please see code details here:
[Code Details](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nlo8QAOUy2ssOetdAMbB?p=preview)

```
this._HttpService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => this.items = data);
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You don't get access to the local filesystem easily in javascript - even if you have this set up, your url will need to begin `file://` you probably mean to grab the `json` from the same server that's hosting the angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting, start with angular5, You need to import **`HttpClientModule`** instead of **`Http`** , also you have not added it inside app.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-589vdz?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

please import HttpModule in your app.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,HttpModule],
```